# Why does quoting arguments not do anything in git aliases?

Tags: git, shell, parsing

I have the following `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    print = !printf %s\\\\n a b c
```

It behaves as follows:

```
$ git print
a
b
c
```

But now I change it to the following `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    print = !printf %s\\\\n "a b" c
```

and yet the `a` and `b` still undergo word splitting:

```
$ git print
a
b
c
```

If the `""` quotes aren't preventing word-splitting then what are they doing?
How are the commands parsed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Git's configuration-language parser [uses double quotes for its own purposes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_syntax):

> ... Doublequote `"` and backslash can be included by escaping them as `\"` and `\\`, respectively. Backslashes preceding other characters are dropped when reading; for example, `\t` is read as `t` and `\0` is read as `0` ...

While this particular paragraph is discussing subsection names, the double-quote and double-backslash rules apply outside subsection names as well.  The rest of these quotes apply everywhere, except for the `\t`=`t` kind of thing in subsection names:

> Inside double quotes, double quote `"` and backslash `\` characters must be escaped: use `\"` for `"` and `\\` for `\`.
>
> The following escape sequences (beside `\"` and `\\`) are recognized: `\n` for newline character (NL), `\t` for horizontal tabulation (HT, TAB) and `\b` for backspace (BS). Other char escape sequences (including octal escape sequences) are invalid.

Note that *none of this has anything to do with aliases specifically:* these rules apply to *all* lines in a `.gitconfig` or `.git/config` file.  (This matters in, e.g., submodule paths, though one wouldn't generally *encode* a double quote in one.)

Now, *after* the configuration parser is done reading the `.git/config` file, if the line is in an `alias` section, it defines an alias.  Within that alias, double quotes do prevent word-splitting:

```
[alias]
    foo = log \"a b\"

$ git foo
fatal: ambiguous argument 'a b': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

Note that to get past the configuration parser in the first place, these had to be given with backslashes.  To avoid that particular annoyance we can use single quotes instead:

```
[alias]
    foo = log 'a b'
```

produces the same result.

If the alias is a *shell* alias (prefixed with `!`), the entire string (minus the exclamation point of course) is fed to the shell.  To observe that, use `GIT_TRACE`:

```
[alias]
    foo = !printf %s\\\\n 'a b'

$ GIT_TRACE=1 git foo
23:15:46.947801 git.c:670               trace: exec: git-foo
23:15:46.948153 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: git-foo
23:15:46.948883 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: 'printf %s\\n '\''a b'\'''
a b
```

If we get double quotes past the configuration parser, they have the same effect:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git foo
23:16:24.919042 git.c:670               trace: exec: git-foo
23:16:24.919402 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: git-foo
23:16:24.920114 run-command.c:643       trace: run_command: 'printf %s\\n "a b"'
a b
```

The reason we need four backslashes is, of course, that the Git configuration parser turned them into two backslashes (as shown in the `GIT_TRACE=1` output) and the shell itself then turned them into one backslash, which `printf` combined with the `n` to make a newline.

Attempting the alias:

```
    foo = !printf %s\\\\n "a b
```

fails with:

```
fatal: bad config line 30 in file [path]/.gitconfig
```

because Git itself is running its line-by-line parser and is unhappy with the unclosed quote.

Comment: You are awesome. This is exactly the information I was looking for. And thank you for mentioning `GIT_TRACE` as well!