# How to concatenate string variables that contain space?

Tags: bash, git

I have the following script:

```
foo="foo";
bar="bar";
separator=": ";
result="${foo}${separator}${bar}";
echo $result;
```

I expected to get `foo: bar`, but the output was `foo:bar` - the space was lost.  What am I missing here?

Here is the code of the alias inside .gitconfig:

```
[alias]
    vx = "!f() { foo="foo"; \
              bar="bar"; \
              separator=": "; \
              result="${foo}${separator}${bar}"; \
              echo $result; \
             }; f"
```

P.S. I also tried `result=${foo}${separator}${bar};` without double quotes - didn't work either.
P.P.S.  I should note that this script is running in the confines of a .gitconfig alias.

Comment: Changing `separator=": "` to `separator=': '` seems to work. Apparently git consumes double quotes.

Comment: @oguzismail Thank you.  I would have never occurred to me.

Comment: There's more information on how git's config parser works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56015130/why-does-quoting-arguments-not-do-anything-in-git-aliases).

Comment: You should always be worried when using quotes inside those same quotes. It's hard for languages to know that `"!f() { foo="` isn't a complete string

Comment: Double quotes in double quotes doe not work. You just "unquote" the sentence and the white space will be removed. Running the first code block in my terminal works just fine.